# Finding properties with simple getters/setters of a DTO class

Tags: c#, dto

In my DTO classes, I have some properties wiyth simple getter/setter (`get; set;`) while some of the properties have more complex getters/setters (like evaluating the value by some other property/variable etc)

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClassDto
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get { return Name; } set { Name = value; } }
    ....
}
```

In above example, I want to get property `Name`, but do not want to get `Description`

I am trying to use [`PropertyInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) to find properties which have `get;set;` as getter/setter but failed to do so.

My reason for a such development is; properties with simple `get;set;` have a property with the same name in my Entity classes, alongside with a column in the database table. My Entities also have some properties which do not have a related column on the database table. So getting the properties with simple getters/setters will give me the properties with related database columns.

Meanwhile, I am using NHibernate.

Comment: Use another attribute to flag the fields you want to be used, that's more flexible and very easy to implement.

Comment: You could check the attributes of the getter and setter methods for the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` but I don't know if that will be added for other cases too.

Answer (score 1):

check if this meets your requirment.

```
var property = typeof(MyClassDto).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(t => t.CanRead && t.CanWrite);
            foreach (var item in property)
            {
                string propertyName = item.Name;
                bool CompilerGenerated = item.GetGetMethod()
                      .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Any();
                //Description is not CompilerGeneratedAttribute so return false; 
            }
```

Comment: This will not work as it will return both properties `Name` and `Description` instead of just `Name`.